# Monitor turning off instead of activating the screensaver, how do I prevent it?

Tags: 10.10, power-management, monitor, screensaver

I have a screensaver configured to activate after 5 minutes. When the time elapses, instead of activating the screensaver, my monitor turns off.

I tried playing with settings, and searching the internet, but I couldn't find anything and couldn't figure out how to solve this issue.

Can someone help?

Comment: Have you checked Power Management Preferences(System → Preferences → Power Management) ?

Comment: @karthick87 I disabled them to prevent them from turning off my monitor. Just to make sure - which PM preferences do you mean?

Comment: Did you set Blank screen in your screensaver?If yes it simply displays a black screen.It doesn't mean that your monitor is set off.

Comment: @karthick87 Off course not :P  My monitor is really turned off (the led goes from blue to orange)

Comment: @Vjo Could you maybe set your screensaver timeout to less than 5 minutes, just to see if it works? If it does, then there's still some power management thing going on.

Comment: @chris I tried doing it, and I couldn't find the settings to screen saver. What a bug, eh?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently I screwed up my kubuntu after trying [BSOD screensaver](http://kenfallon.com/?p=733), and I am posting my answer just for references.

I switched to xubuntu-desktop and everything works fine. I didn't try to reinstall kubuntu-desktop, but that might fix the problem.